# Flutter - Unable to load contents of file list xcode_backend.sh

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I'm trying to run my Flutter app in Xcode, and I'm getting this error:

> Unable to load contents of file list: '/bin/sh
> "/Users/user235577/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh"
> build'

Yep the path its correct. But I don't know what to do.
I have done pod deintegrate, flutter clean, etc etc etc

Nothing changes.

Its driving me crazy tbh. I dont know how to provide more informations, I dont even know where the problem is around.

Can you guys please help me? Here its my project https://github.com/luangs7/MyNextBook-Flutter

Thank you.

[image]

[image]